# Not able to recreate Index Column in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

In SharePoint Online, a managed metadata site column is added to a contenttype in a contenttype-hub and subscribed within a Record Center sitecollection. A document library is created using the contenttype and an Index column is also created for the metadata column. Due to some reason, I have deleted the index column and now the column is missing from the **Primary column for this index dropdown**.

I can create index columns with the available columns from the UI and from powershell.

I have tried the following without any luck:

- Reindex the library and sitecollection
- Recreated the library
- Recreated the sitecollection
- Following powershell script is working for available columns but not for the missing one:

  `$field= $list.Fields.GetByTitle("Column Name");
  $field.Indexed = $true;
  $field.Update();
  $clientContext.Load($field);
  $clientContext.ExecuteQuery();`
- Receiving the following error on **ExecuteQuery()**.

**Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot complete this action. Please try again."**

I need the column to be indexed to avoid **List View Threshold issue**.
Please help!!!